# Converting DFA to Regular Expression (DFA final state is the empty set)

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-automata

So the original question is to get the complement of the regex 0*1*.
0*1* = {ε,0,1,00,01,11,000,001,011,111,...}, essentially any number of 0s followed by any number of 1s.

I made this DFA for 0*1*:

- **Note: "↫" denotes a self-loop.**

->**((q1))↫0** ---1--> **((q2))↫1** ---0---> **(∅)↫0,1**

Then I did the complement by swapping the final states with the non final states, resulting in the empty set being the only final state:

-->**(q1)↫0** ---1--> **(q2)↫1** ---0---> **((∅))↫0,1**

But now I'm confused, I've looked at countless examples online and I'm not sure how to convert this particular DFA to a regex, my main problem being that the final state is an empty set.

These are the computations I did:

> For q1:
>
> q1 = Ɛ + q1(0), because R=Q+RP is equal to R=QP*...
>
> q1 = Ɛ(0*), because Ɛ(R)=R...
>
> q1 = 0*
>
> Then, for q2:
>
> q2=q1(1)+q2(1), substitute q1 to get q2=0*(1)+q2(1), then...
>
> q2=0*1(1)*
>
> For ∅: (<-This is where I think things start to get shaky)
>
> ∅ = q2(0) + ∅(0) + ∅(1), can be reorganized ∅ = q2(0) + ∅(0 + 1), then substitute q2 and get ∅ = 0*1(1)*0 + ∅(0 + 1), then this can become:
>
> ∅ = 0*1(1)* 0(0 + 1)*

So I would consider the complement of the regex 0*1* to be 0*1(1)* 0(0 + 1)*.  But that just doesn't seem right.  Am I overcomplicating this?  Please any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1:
- Edited to fix typos

Comment: Can't you just use q3 instead of the empty set?

Comment: @KennyLau So it doesn't matter that in the DFA it is an empty set?  That's the crux of my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start at state $A$.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{State}&\text{Next}&\text{Goto}\\\hline
A&0&A\\\hline
A&1&B\\\hline
B&0&C\\\hline
B&1&B\\\hline
C&0&C\\\hline
C&1&C
\end{array}$$

where states $A$ and $B$ are accepted.

---

In its complement, $C$ is accepted.

We have these paths from $A$ to $C$ forcing no repetition of states:

- $A \overset{1}{\longmapsto} B \overset{0}{\longmapsto} C$

There's only one path.

This corresponds to the regex `0*11*0[01]*`, which can be shortened to `0*1+0.*` assuming that `.` only matches `0` or `1`.

Comment: I see I made some typos.  I appreciate you accounting for that.  So an empty set in a DFA can be treated like any other state (i.e. a q3)?  In other words, there are no special rules to follow in regards to the empty set being a final state as opposed to a non-empty set as a final state when writing the regex for the DFA?

Comment: @antcny I may be mistaken, but are states in DFA sets?

Comment: No you are correct, my misunderstanding I just realized.  I believe I could just treat the empty set as a q3.  All that matters is that q3 is a non-accepting/non-final state.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @antcny Are states sets?

Comment: States are not sets.

Comment: @antcny then what is "the empty set as a state"?

Comment: the empty set is used for subset/powerset construction when converting an NFA to a DFA, it turns out the empty set isn't necessary in this case.